# How can I Hide the "Move Window to Left Side of Screen" option of window's resize button on Macos programmatically?

Tags: macos, nswindow

There is a Hover Menu on my macos application's titlebar resize button. The Hover Menu is the same thing as the belowing picture shows.

[image: hover menu]

I know how to control title bar's buttons following the instruction of [nswindowstylemask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowstylemask). But I have no idea **What can I to to make the special menu never show programmatically?**

Comment: ```macOS``` does not provide a direct API to control the visibility of the specific context menu that appears when you click on the title bar resize button. This is a system-level context menu that is automatically generated by the operating system and is not customizable through the public APIs provided by Apple.